# character set and collation messed up?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm writing an html5 web page to store input from users in a MySQL database.
The web page has tags `<html lang="en">`, `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<form ... accept-charset="utf-8">`.

I'm using PHP 5.4 and MariaDB 5.5.44. The database's character's set to `UTF8`. The table's character's set to `UTF8`. Collation is set to `utf8_general_ci`.

Why am I getting weird characters in my database? E.g. when I upload "á" it becomes "Ã¡"?

I'm pretty much a noob at coding and the docs go above my skill level.

Comment: hey Mark, thanks for pointing that out. I had been looking through articles for over an hour and this one didn't pop up in the results (or it got drowned in all the other charset/collation/utf8 entries). Seems like a decent article, definitely going to bookmark it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: 
Directly after the DB connection initialisation, insert

```
$mydb->set_charset("utf8");
```

(where $mydb is the variable for your db connection)
In my case this helped in a similar situation.

Comment: Oh man, you're the best :)
I'm using PDO, so the statement's syntax is a little different but indeed I forgot to put the charset to utf8 in the db connection.